# execute immediate not showing records of Dynamic Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created Anonymous block which is creating Select statement dynamically. when I execute block its only showing anonymous block completed but not showing SQL output.

```
declare
    sql_stmt clob; 
    pivot_clause clob; 
begin 
    select listagg('''' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || ''' as "' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || '"', ',') 
    within group (order by PERIOD_NAME) 
    into pivot_clause
    from   ( select TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') PERIOD_NAME 
             from table1 
             where request_id=<id> 
             group by TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') 
             order by TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') ASC );

     sql_stmt := 'select * from (select PERIOD_NAME, depreciation 
                                 from table1) pivot (sum(depreciation) for PERIOD_NAME in (' || pivot_clause || '))';

     execute immediate sql_stmt; 
 end;
```

Comment: Execute immediate isn't intended for SELECT's.

Comment: You must use `execute immediate sql_stmt INTO ...; `

Answer (score 4):

As you don't know the structure in advance, because of the dynamic pivot to an unknown number of columns in the result set, you could use a ref cursor to retrieve the result of the dynamic query.

This uses SQL*Plus/SQL Developer/SQLcl bind variables;

```
variable rc refcursor;

declare
  sql_stmt clob; 
  pivot_clause clob; 
begin 
  select listagg('''' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || ''' as "' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || '"', ',') 
  within group (order by PERIOD_NAME) 
  into pivot_clause from (select TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') PERIOD_NAME 
                          from table1 
                          where request_id=<id> 
                          GROUP BY TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') 
                          order by TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') ASC); 
  sql_stmt := 'select * from (select PERIOD_NAME, depreciation 
                              from table1) pivot (sum(depreciation) for PERIOD_NAME in (' || pivot_clause || '))';

  open :rc for sql_stmt; 
end;
/

print rc
```

The [client `variable` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm)

```
variable rc refcursor;
```

declares the variable and data type of the client bind variable, as a reference cursor. Then rather than using `execute immediate` it does [open for](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/OPEN-FOR-statement.html) with your dynamic statement:

```
  open :rc for sql_stmt;
```

which opens the ref cursor with the results of that query. (Notice the `:` at the start of `:rc`, indicating that is a bind variable reference not a local PL/SQL variable).

Then outside the block you can [print](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm) the result set with:

```
print rc
```

Different clients/IDEs will need different syntax. You could do something similar over JDBC too. You could also have a function that returns a `sys_refcursor`. But it depends what your end goal for this is.

---

Incidentally, at the moment you'll get null for all the pivoted totals; your final query needs to get `PERIOD_NAME` in the same format the pivot clause is looking for, e.g.

```
  sql_stmt := 'select * from (select to_char(to_date(PERIOD_NAME, ''MON-YYYY''), ''MON-YY'') as PERIOD_NAME, depreciation 
                              from table1) pivot (sum(depreciation) for PERIOD_NAME in (' || pivot_clause || '))';
```

though it woudl be slightly simpler to leave the original format in the pivot clause instead:

```
declare
  sql_stmt clob; 
  pivot_clause clob; 
begin 

  select listagg('''' || PERIOD_NAME || ''' as "' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_DATE,'MON-YY') || '"', ',') 
  within group (order by PERIOD_DATE) 
  into pivot_clause from (select distinct PERIOD_NAME, TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') PERIOD_DATE 
                          from table1 
                          where request_id=<id>); 

  sql_stmt := 'select * from (select PERIOD_NAME, depreciation 
                              from table1) pivot (sum(depreciation) for PERIOD_NAME in (' || pivot_clause || '))';

  open :rc for sql_stmt; 
end;
/
```

With a dummy table and data:

```
create table table1 (request_id, period_name, depreciation) as
select 1, 'JAN-2018', 42 from dual
union all select 1, 'FEB-2018', 11 from dual
union all select 1, 'MAR-2018', 22 from dual
union all select 1, 'MAR-2018', 33 from dual
union all select 2, 'MAR-2018', 44 from dual;
```

running either version and doing `print rc` shows:

```
    JAN-18     FEB-18     MAR-18
---------- ---------- ----------
        42         11         99
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. But when I print rc its not showing records in rows and columns. Please help.

Comment: @PrashantKulkarni - did you see my edit, explaining how to fix that? Your original pivot clause was based on the shorter MON-YY values so nothing matched the longer MON-YYYY values form the table. I showed two ways to fix that.

Comment: When I execute procedure and print rc I am getting expected result ie records I am getting are correctly matching. but only thing is it's not coming in rows and column as expected. Sorry if I dont understand your given solution correctly.

Comment: You should be getting one column for each month, as in my demo. You won't get multiple rows though as both the columns you select are consumed by the pivot. Why were you expecting multiple rows, and what would they show?

Answer (score 1):

You can only select a dynamic sql into some variables.

Example:

```
declare
    v_sql VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_col1 varchar2(100);
    v_col2 varchar2(100);
    v_col3 varchar2(100);
begin
    v_sql := 'SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO  v_col1, v_col2, v_col3;

    dbms_output.put_line('v_col1: ' || v_col1);
    dbms_output.put_line('v_col2: ' || v_col2);
    dbms_output.put_line('v_col3: ' || v_col3); 
end;
```

If you got multiple rows you have to use a Cursor:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE c IS REF CURSOR;

    v_c    c;
    v_sql        VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_col1       VARCHAR2(100);
    v_col2       VARCHAR2(100);      
BEGIN
    v_sql := 'SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 3, 4 FROM DUAL';

    OPEN v_c FOR v_sql;

    LOOP
        FETCH v_c INTO v_col1, v_col2;
        EXIT WHEN v_c%NOTFOUND;

        dbms_output.put_line('v_col1: ' || v_col1 || ', v_col2: ' || v_col2);

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE v_c;
END;
```

Comment: I am using listagg function which is in cluase for pivot. As listagg o/p dynamic in nature I cant select particular columns here.

Comment: Added a Cursor-Example für multi-row-looping.

Comment: Hi @kara, I tried in 11g, its not printing results. just returned as `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Comment: @Rj_N Does you dbms_output work? You should check if you can write to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a way to give the values back to your program so you need an INTO clause.

As you are returning a set of rows you will need a structure to store it.

For the sake of an example the following creates a dynamic query selecting from the ALL_OBJECTS view and puts the results into a collection.

```
DECLARE
   sql_stmt     CLOB;
   TYPE my_rec_rt IS RECORD
   ( owner         VARCHAR2(30),
     object_name   VARCHAR2(30) );
   TYPE my_rec_t IS TABLE OF my_rec_rt;
   obj_record   my_rec_t;
BEGIN
   sql_stmt :=
      q'[select owner, object_name from all_objects where owner = 'ODS']';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO obj_record;
END;
```

How you go through the collection subsequently depends on your requirements.

(You can find this documented in the Oracle docs at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317 )

Comment: I am using listagg function which is 'in cluase' for pivot. As listagg o/p is dynamic in nature I cant select particular columns here. Pls advise.

Comment: In that case you need to use the techniques in the answer by Alex Poole.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query it could be this:

```
declare
    sql_stmt clob; 
    pivot_clause clob; 

    v_PERIOD_NAME DATE;
    v_depreciation NUMBER;
begin 
    select listagg('''' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || ''' as "' || TO_CHAR(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY') || '"', ',') 
    within group (order by PERIOD_NAME) 
    into pivot_clause
    from   ( select TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') PERIOD_NAME 
             from table1 
             where request_id=<id> 
             group by TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') 
             order by TO_DATE(PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YYYY') ASC );

     sql_stmt := 'select * from (select PERIOD_NAME, depreciation 
                                 from table1) pivot (sum(depreciation) for PERIOD_NAME in (' || pivot_clause || '))';

     execute immediate sql_stmt INTO v_PERIOD_NAME, v_depreciation;
     dbms_output.put_line('v_PERIOD_NAME: ' || v_PERIOD_NAME); 
     dbms_output.put_line('v_depreciation: ' || v_depreciation); 
 end;
```

Note, this presumes that you will get only (and always) a single row back from the query. Otherwise you get exception `NO_DATA_FOUND`, resp. `TOO_MANY_ROWS`.

Comment: The two columns form `table1` are pivoted into an unknown number of columns... they aren't selected directly.

Comment: @AlexPoole, yes you are right, I don't work that often with PIVOT so I am not used to it. Anyway, I will leave my answer to demonstrate the basic principle.