# Oracle/SQL -Sales broken out by Months

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have created the following query to pull total order by month for a salesMen. while this gets me the data I need for a single salesmen i need to run this for more than just one. what I would like to accomplish is a query that pull for several different salesmen and is broken out by month and the Months being the Columns names(Columns dynamic to months being pulled). Like below.

```
 SalesMen   -   10-2017     - 11-2017 - 12-2017 - 01/2018
------------------------------------------------------------
Salesmen_1   Month_total(5)    15       300       100
Salesmen_2       100          948       821       684
```

Current Code:

```
select (case when region_code in ('123','124') then 'SalesMen_1' else 'N/A' end)SalesMen, to_char(DATE_ENTERED, 'MM-YYYY') as MM_YYYY, Count(ORder_NO) as Month_Total
from ORDERS 
where 
REGEXP_like (ORder_NO, '^W|^E')
and DATE_ENTERED between ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 2), 'YYYY') || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), -3) and TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM')|| '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - 1
and region_code in ('123','124')
group by  to_char(DATE_ENTERED, 'MM-YYYY'),(case when region_code in ('123','124') then 'SalesMen_1' else 'N/A' end)
order by to_char(DATE_ENTERED, 'MM-YYYY') desc
```

Results:
[Current Results Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV6XW.png)

Comment: look up PIVOT, it seems like what you want from your current results and desired ones.

Comment: If the month range is dynamic, though, you'll have to use dynamic SQL for the pivot. [This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51743956/266304) was doing something similar, pivoting on months, so that could give you a starting point.

Comment: Thank you Pivot helped me achieve what I wanted.